# np.argmax that returns tuple

Tags: python, numpy, argmax

I have a matrix `A` of shape `(n, m, s)`. At each position in the 0th axis, I need the position corresponding to the maximum in the `(m, s)`-shaped array.

For example:

```
np.random.seed(1)
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=[10, 3, 3])
```

`A[0]` is:

```
array([[5, 8, 9],
       [5, 0, 0],
       [1, 7, 6]])
```

I want to obtain `(0, 2)`, i.e. the position of `9` here.

I would love to do
`aa = A.argmax()`, such that `aa.shape = (10, 2)`, and `aa[0] = [0, 2]`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is clearly mentioned in the documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `np.unravel_index` with a list comprehension:

```py
out = [np.unravel_index(np.argmax(block, axis=None), block.shape) for block in array]
```

where `block` will be the `3x3` (`m x s`) shaped array in each turn.

This gives a list with 10 (`n`) entries:

```
[(0, 2), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 1), (2, 0), (1, 2), (0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)]
```

You can convert this to a numpy array (of desired shape `(n, 2)`):

```py
aa = np.array(out)
```

to get:

```
array([[0, 2],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: You don't need the final reshape

Answer (score 2):

One of the `vectorized-version` solution is given by [Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67191104/14867730)
 which is recommended for speed and easy vector operation but you find solution using basic python inbuilt operation.

**LOGIC :**

`np.argmax` return max value in `flattened` as `axis default argument` is `None` which means it operate on matrix by taking it as vector.
**1.** `// integer operation` will result `row-number` and,
**2.** `% module operation` will result `column-number`

```
result = [(np.argmax(i)//3, (np.argmax(i)%3)) for i in array]
```

For Python 3.8+ use `:=` operator for single time computation:

```
result = [(y//3, y%3) for i in array if (y := np.argmax(i))]
```

[image]

**CODE:**

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
array = np.random.randint(0,10,size=[10, 3, 3])

result = [(np.argmax(i)//3, (np.argmax(i)%3)) for i in array]
print(result)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[(0, 2), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 1), (2, 0), (1, 2), (0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: Mustafa's version is not vectorized: it has an explicit loop

Comment: You're calling `argmax` twice on each sub-array.

Comment: Thanks for correction but during `list comp` it is not possible to `create variable` :)

Comment: It is in python 3.8+. It's also a good indication that a list comprehension is not the best tool here

Comment: Using the `:=` operator

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `unravel_index`, which does the same thing in one function call.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally much faster to run [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) a partially flattened version of the array than to use a comprehension:

```
ind = A.reshape(A.shape[0], -1).argmax(axis=-1)
```

Now you can apply [`unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) to get the 2D index:

```
coord = np.unravel_index(ind, A.shape[1:])
```

`coord` is a pair of arrays, one for each axis. You can convert to a list of tuples using a common python idiom:

```
result = list(zip(*coord))
```

A better way is just to stack the arrays together into an Nx2 array. This will behave as a sequence of pairs for all intents and purposes:

```
result = np.stack(coord, axis=-1)
```

Obligatory one-liner:

```
result = np.stack(np.unravel_index(A.reshape(A.shape[0], -1).argmax(axis=-1), A.shape[1:]), axis=-1)
```